# Use OpenCL with scala, java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, opencl, intel

I am using eclipse with java and scala via the package link:
    http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/3.0.2.vfinal-210-20131028/scala-SDK-3.0.2-vfinal-2.10-win32.win32.x86_64.zip

I imported some libraries that use openCL, and when I attempt to use them, I get the run-time error:

```
can not create command queue on CLDevice [id: 8791129068288 name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 type:     
GPU profile: FULL_PROFILE] with properties: [OUT_OF_ORDER_MODE] [error: CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES]
com.jogamp.opencl.CLException$CLInvalidQueuePropertiesException: can not create command queue on 
CLDevice [id: 8791129068288 name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 type: GPU profile: FULL_PROFILE] with 
properties: [OUT_OF_ORDER_MODE] [error: CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES]
```

I have an 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000', (Under 'device manager'>'display adapters')

I have also installed the runtime and application SDKs for Intel via:
    http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/3782/intel_sdk_for_ocl_applications_2013_r3_runtime_x64_setup.msi
    http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/3782/intel_sdk_for_ocl_applications_2013_r3_x64_setup.exe

Comment: Looks like Intel HD 4000's drivers cannot handle out of order command queues. Maybe there are too many queues.

Comment: I also installed jocl:    http://www.jocl.org/downloads/JOCL-0.1.9-bin.zip and linked the jocl.jar to my project. I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe its a hardware issue? Have you tried that for CPU or discrete gpu?

Answer (score 0):

HD Graphics does not support creation of out of order command queues. Its supported on the CPU, though.

Thanks.